# How to refactor this piece of code into a more reactive one

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, project-reactor

We are building microservices using Spring Cloud Stream.

We have this piece of code running, which basically subscribes to Messages from the **Tasks** channel with a specific **type** header, execute a job and then publish a new Message to the **Events** channel:

```
@EnableBinding({InboundChannels.class, OutboundChannels.class})
public class TasksProcessor {

private final UserService userService;
private final MessageChannel eventsChannel;
private final Logger logger;

public TasksProcessor(
        UserService userService,
        @Qualifier(OutboundChannels.EVENTS) MessageChannel eventsChannel,
        Logger logger
) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.eventsChannel = eventsChannel;
    this.logger = logger;
}

    @StreamListener(value = TASKS, condition = "headers['type']=='" + CREATE_USER + "'")
    public void createUser(User user)  {
        userService.save(user)
            .subscribe(created -> {
                Message<User> successMessage = Events.create(Events.USER_CREATED, created).build();
                eventsChannel.send(successMessage);
            });
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is any better, more reactive way of implementing it leveraging the `spring-cloud-stream-reactive` API.

After trying that:

```
@StreamListener(value = TASKS, condition = "headers['type']=='" + CREATE_USER + "'")
public @Output(EVENTS) Flux<Message<User>> createUser(Flux<User> users)  {
       return users.flatMap(userService::save)
            .map(e -> Events.create(Events.USER_CREATED, created).build());
}
```

I get this error on application startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a condition for methods that return a value
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:116)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMethodUtils.validateStreamListenerMethod(StreamListenerMethodUtils.java:86)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$DefaultStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.orchestrateStreamListenerSetupMethod(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:352)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.doPostProcess(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:195)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$0(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:167)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.injectAndPostProcessDependencies(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:105)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:777)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
... 49 more
```

So I tried a more generic approach:

```
@StreamListener(value = TASKS)
public @Output(EVENTS) Flux<Message<?>> reducer(Flux<Message<?>> messages)  {
    return messages
            .filter(message -> message.getHeaders().containsKey(TYPE_HEADER))
            .flatMap(message -> {
                final String type = (String) message.getHeaders().get(TYPE_HEADER);

                switch (type) {

                    case CREATE_USER:
                        final User toCreate = (User) message.getPayload();
                        return userService.save(toCreate)
                                .map(created -> Events.create(USER_CREATED, created).build());


                    default:
                        return null;
                }

            });
}
```

But that didn't work either since `message.getPayload()` is of type `byte[]` and I didn't find out how to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
@StreamListener(value = TASKS, condition = "headers['type']=='" + CREATE_USER + "'")
public @Output(EVENTS) Flux<Message<User>> createUser(Flux<User> users)  {
           return users.flatMap(userService::save)
                .map(e -> Events.create(Events.USER_CREATED, created).build());
}
```

As far as your `UserService.save(User)` returns `Mono<User>`.

See sample in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RC3/reference/htmlsingle/#_reactor_based_handlers). Also pay attention to the [Reactive Sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/processor-samples/reactive-processor).

The main point of the Reactive support through the Framework that you shouldn't *subscribe* to the `Publisher` provided for you by that Framework.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I will test that tomorrow at work and then, if it works, I can accept your answer!! But before you go, can you please explain me exactly why I shouldn't subscribe to the publisher?

Comment: Well, you can do that for your own `Publisher` chains, but when you use provided by the Framework, would be better to delegate all the hard work to the Framework. You don't know what else it is going to do before and after your functionality. And you may break the behavior and back-pressure nature of the Reactive Streams composition. I think more info you can find in the WebFlux Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#spring-webflux

Comment: Nice, that makes sense, but your code didn't work :( I added some logs

Comment: That's not problem of my code, that's how you use Framework. According that exception you can't use `condition` on the `@StreamListener` when there is some return value. You should consider to move that condition (`.filter()`?) to the `Flux` in the method body. You can find such an info in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RC3/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_streamlistener_for_dispatching_messages_to_multiple_methods: `it must be an individual message handling method (reactive API methods are not supported)`

Comment: I see, I will update my question with some more info, but thank you so far, you have been very helpful